# What is the equivalent of bash export in Perl?

Tags: perl, bash, export

I am converting a bash script to Perl. I am not sure what the equivalent of an `export` is.

```
LOC=/tmp/1/
export LOC
```

For example, for the above two lines, what would be the equivalent Perl code?

```
my $LOC = '/tmp/1/';
# what should go here?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ENV{LOC} = "/tmp/1";
```

The contents of [`%ENV`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlvar#ENV) are propagated to the environment of the child processes of a Perl script.

Comment: but not to the parent shell (which is often the unstated need with this particular FAQ)

Comment: Any changes to the environment are not propagated to the parent in Linux. That's because in Linux, every process has its own environment.  But in Windows, there's only one environment, so any changes to it appear in all the processes.

Comment: To **unborn child** processes, rather.

Comment: @shawnhcorey - I don't think that comment about Windows is true. Try `set FOO=1`, `perl -e '$ENV{FOO}=2`, `echo %FOO%`

Answer (score 4):

Module Env (see http://perldoc.perl.org/Env.html)

Comment: +1: Interesting...One caveat: it looks like it might be hard to create a new env var on the fly; the mechanism seems to rely on you specifying the environment variables to be tied at compilation time (`use Env;`).  So, if you know you'll need `$ENV{LOC}`, then it is fine: `use Env qw(LOC);`.  If you decide part way through your script you need a new env var, you appear to be stuck with using the `$ENV{NEWVAR}` mechanism rather than module `Env`.

Comment: Interesting, but I'm not convinced it's all that useful (I've never used it myself).  It just means you can type `$LOC` rather than `$ENV{LOC}`, which I'd say just makes it harder to see what's going on.  (And it treats `$PATH` as a Perl array.)

Answer (score 0):

Inside the bash, you might want to do something like this:

```
EXPORT_CMD=/tmp/${0}_exports.bsh
perl ...
chmod +x $EXPORT_CMD
$EXPORT_CMD
rm $EXPORT_CMD
```

Inside the Perl, this:

```
sub export (@) {
    state $exh;
    unless ( $exh ) {
        my $export_cmd_path = $ENV{EXPORT_CMD};
        open( $exh, '>>', $export_cmd_path )
            or die "Could not open $export_cmd_path!"
            ;
    }
    while ( @_ > 1 ) { 
        my ( $name, $value ) = (( uc shift ), shift );
        # If you want it visible in the current script:
        {   no strict 'refs';
            ${"::$name"} = $value;
        }
        $exh->print( qq{export $name "$value"\n} );
    }
}
```

And then, it's simply a matter of coding this:

```
export LOC => '/tmp/1/';
```

The problem is that most programs cannot change shell variables that they were called from.